# Check files in Documents, Library or tmp directory on iOS device

Tags: ios

I am making on an app and want to get access to the directories that system create automatically when app installed on device. Of course when I use simulator I can find these directories without any problems, but how to open them on device. Maybe via iTunes or maybe Xcode has access to these directories.

The folders are below:

[image]

Why I need it:

Because after my app restore some products (iOS simulator does not support StoreKit) I have few records in the tmp folder in SQLite database.

Comment: Do you want to access it programmatically from your app?

Comment: I just what to open files SQLite db that's why need access to this folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@neilco , it's not necessary to use 3d party tools for this. In Xcode, go to organizer, select the connected device, "applications" tab, select desired application and hit "export" button below. This will export you app to your mac, so you can see your depicted folder structure, files' contents etc.

Comment: thank you. I use Xcode 4.6.3. In organizer it is "Download" button instead of "Export". But in any case these are just details, by the fact it is really helpful answer.

Comment: On Xcode 6.2, Go to **Devices**, select your device, **Installed Apps** and select your app. Choose **Download Container**, it will generate a .xcappdata file. Choose **Show Package Contents**.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at using [iExplorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/) as this allows you to views the folder structure of apps on a device.